# Assigning values to a referenced instance

Tags: java, class, methods, reference, instances

I am an intermediate Java beginner and also completely new to stack overflow. (This is my first post.)

I have a question about the following code and the assignment of values to a reference.

First, the code:

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class DrawPlayerAndSnake
{
  static void initializeToken( Point p, int i )
  {
    int randomX = (int)(Math.random() * 40); // 0 <= x < 40
    int randomY = (int)(Math.random() * 10); // 0 <= y < 10
    p.setLocation( randomX, randomY );
    /*
    System.out.println("The position of the player is " + playerPosition + ".");
    i = i + randomX;
    System.out.println(" i lautet " + i + ".");
    */
    Point x = new Point(10,10);
    System.out.println("The position of the x is " + x + ".");
    System.out.println("The position of the p is " + p + ".");    
    p.setLocation(x);
    x.x = randomX;
    x.y = randomY;
    p = x;
    System.out.println("The position of the p is now" + p + ".");
    System.out.println("The x position of the p is now " + p.getX() + ".");  

  }

  static void printScreen( Point playerPosition,
                       Point snakePosition )
  {
    for ( int y = 0; y < 10; y++ )
    {
      for ( int x = 0; x < 40; x++ )
      {
        if ( playerPosition.distanceSq( x, y ) == 0 )
          System.out.print( '&' );
        else if ( snakePosition.distanceSq( x, y ) == 0 )
          System.out.print( 'S' );
        else System.out.print( '.' );
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    Point playerPosition = new Point();
    Point snakePosition  = new Point();

    System.out.println( playerPosition );
    System.out.println( snakePosition );
    int i = 2;
    initializeToken( playerPosition , i );
    initializeToken( snakePosition, i);

    System.out.println( playerPosition );
    System.out.println( snakePosition );

    printScreen( playerPosition, snakePosition );
  }
}
```

This code is modified for educational purposes (I am trying to understand this). The original code is out of the book "Java ist auch eine Insel" by Chrisitan Ullenboom.

Okay, now there is this method  *intializeToken* and I am passing over an instance of the class *Point*. (I hope i get that right, so if I make a mistake please feel free to correct me.)
When this method is called by the main method, a new reference to - say - the instance *playerPosition* is created by *Point p*.
Now, because the parameter *playerPosition* which is passed over to method *initializeToken* is not final I can do whichever assignment to point *p* that I want.

But when I create a new point object with the reference variable *x* and assign this reference to *p* by *p = x;* the x and y position of *playerPosition* won't change, but by *p.setLocation()* it does.

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Think of `p` as a reference to a `Point`, not as a `Point` itself.

Comment: Because java is pass by value.

Comment: This is better explained here: [Is Java “pass-by-reference”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/1065197)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Point p passed into initializeToken is a local reference to the instance of p stored in memory. When you call p.setLocation(), you are "dereferencing" p, that is, modifying the actual instance in memory. However, if you simply set p = new Point(x, y), you are modifying the local variable in the initializeToken method, which will disappear once the method terminates.